# How to print a partial list of alias definitions in tcsh?

Tags: alias, tcsh

I'm working on Fedora 18 with tcsh on a network with a lot of pre-defined aliases. I'm adding my own personal aliases as well, but I want to be able to display these in a separate list.

Right now I have a `.cshrc` file that loads alias definitions from a `.alias` file. This is the file with the pre-defined aliases. I thought to create a second file named `.myalias`, put my personal aliases there, and have `.cshrc` load that as well. That works fine.

Sadly, using the `alias` command only lists ALL defined aliases. I want to list only my personal aliases from the `.myalias` file, but in the same format as the output from the `alias` command. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No I do not believe there is any way to distinguish between the aliases coming from the system or from your `.myaliases` file. I typically use `grep` or `less` and pipe the output of the `alias` command to either to find what I want.

Additionally I'd typically grep through the contents of a file such as `.myalias` to find what I'm looking for.

#### Example

Say I have the following aliases.

```
$ alias
egrep   egrep --color=auto
fgrep   fgrep --color=auto
grep    grep --color=auto
l.  ls -d .* --color=auto
ll  ls -l --color=auto
ls  ls --color=auto
mc  source /usr/libexec/mc/mc-wrapper.csh
vi  vim
which   alias | /usr/bin/which --tty-only --read-alias --show-dot --show-tilde
```

I'd find the definition of `fgrep` like so:

```
$ alias | grep "^fgrep"
fgrep   fgrep --color=auto
```

You can also use `less` to give yourself a view of multiple pages of aliases that you can then move back and forth through using the arrow keys or you can search through the output using the forward slash (<kbd>/</kbd>) followed by whatever string you're looking for.

```
$ alias | less
```

Comment: Great, the `grep` tip specifying a string really helped. I used that and a naming convention so that all my aliases start with "mc". Then `$ alias | grep "^mc *"` works for me. Thanks!

Comment: @M.Carney - glad to hear it helped. Thanks for the Q!